# Disable back button in react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I'm using react native navigation (react-navigation) StackNavigator. 
it starts from the Login page throughout the whole lifecycle of the app. I don't want to have a back option, returning to the Login screen. Does anyone know how it can be hidden on the screen after the login screen?
BTW, I'm also hiding it in the login screen by using:

```js
const MainStack = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Login",
      header: {
        visible: false,
      },
    },
  },
  // ... other screens here
})
```

Comment: in versin 4 and older try this: 
`headerLeft:()=>null`

Answer (score 296, accepted):

### **1) To make the back button disappear in react-navigation**

**v5 or newer**:

```
{     
    navigationOptions:  {
    title: 'MyScreen',
    headerLeft: ()=> null,
    // `headerLeft: undefined` should work too
    // `headerLeft: null` should work but could trigger a TS error
}
```

**NOTE:**
**v6** has an extra option:
`headerBackVisible: false`​

> Whether the back button is
> visible in the header. You can use it to show a back button alongside
> headerLeft if you have specified it.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#headerbackvisible

**v2-v4:**

```
navigationOptions:  {
    title: 'MyScreen',
    headerLeft: null
}
```

### **2) If you want to clean navigation stack:**

Assuming you are on the screen from which you want to navigate from:

**If you are using react-navigation version v5 or newer** you can use `navigation.reset` or `CommonActions.reset`:

```
 // Replace current navigation state with a new one,
 // index value will be the current active route:

navigation.reset({
  index: 0,
  routes: [{ name: 'Profile' }],
});
```

Source and more info here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#reset

Or:

```
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 1,
    routes: [
      { name: 'Home' },
      {
        name: 'Profile',
        params: { user: 'jane' },
      },
    ],
  })
);
```

Source and more info here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset

### For older versions of react-navigation:

**v2-v4** use `StackActions.reset(...)`

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0, // <-- currect active route from actions array
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'myRouteWithDisabledBackFunctionality' }),
  ],
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

**v1** use `NavigationActions.reset`

### **3) For android you will also have to disable the hardware back button using the BackHandler**:

http://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler.html

or if you want to use hooks:

https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks#usebackhandler

otherwise the app will close at android hardware back button press if navigation stack is empty.

Additional sources: thank you to the users that added comments below and helped keeping this answer updated for v5+.

Comment: This will remove back button, but in android we can still navigate using device back button. Is there a way to disable that as well?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45953573) expands on how to add params to this navigate action. The [official navigate documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#navigate-link-to-other-screens) is also helpful.

Comment: If you reset the navigation (which you should if you're actually trying to prevent navigating back to the previous screen) I don't believe you need to nullify the header as well, as it happens automatically.

Comment: And when you're in 2018 use "StackAction.reset(...)" instead of "NavigationActions.reset(...)", see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html

Comment: @FlorinDobre `headerLeft: null` is not really right way for v5 due to TS warnings, need to use `headerLeft: () => null`

Comment: Note: In `headerLeft: null` with Typescript I was getting an error in the options of the Navigator. So I had to use `undefined` instead.

Comment: V6^ ```headerBackVisible: false,```

Comment: `If you want to clean navigation stack` typically conditional rendering based navigation is better than reset actions

Answer (score 59):

Have you considered using `this.props.navigation.replace( "HomeScreen" )` instead of `this.props.navigation.navigate( "HomeScreen" )`.

This way you are not adding anything to the stack. so HomeScreen won't wave anything to go back to if back button pressed in Android or screen swiped to the right in IOS.

More informations check the [Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#docsNav).
And of course you can hide the back button by setting `headerLeft: null` in `navigationOptions`

Comment: you cannot pass params using replace.

Comment: you should do for warning error fix  ` ()=>null`

Comment: tq it works... params can be passed as well

Answer (score 22):

We need to set false to the `gesturesEnabled` along with `headerLeft` to `null`. Because we can navigate back by swiping the screen as well.

```
navigationOptions:  {
   title: 'Title',
   headerLeft: null,
   gestureEnabled: false,
}
```

Comment: gesturesEnabled doesnt even exist as property!

Comment: Nice! gestureEnabled is exactly what I was looking for. Thx a lot!!

Answer (score 22):

If your react navigation v6.x

```
options={{
   title: "Detail Pembayaran",
   headerTitleStyle:{
      fontWeight:'bold',
   },
   headerBackVisible:false
}}
```

Reference : [React document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#headerbackbutton)

Comment: This is the only solution that removed the default back button on Android for me.

Comment: simple and to the point. worked for me. thanks!

Comment: can confirm that this works, thank you

Answer (score 18):

You can hide the back button using `left:null`, but for android devices it's still able to go back when the user presses the back button. You need to reset the navigation state and hide the button with `left:null`

Here are the docs for resetting navigation state:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions#reset

This solution works for `react-navigator 1.0.0-beta.7`, however `left:null` no longer works for the latest version.

Comment: on iOS you can still slide from the edge of the screen to pop back. Resetting the navigation state is definitely needed.

Answer (score 14):

using the BackHandler from react native worked for me. Just include this line in your ComponentWillMount:

```
BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {return true})
```

it will disable back button on android device.

Comment: This is Android only.

Answer (score 8):

**For react-navigation V6.0**

```
<Stack.Screen
          name={'Dashboard'}
          component={Dashboard}
          options={{
            gestureEnabled: false,
            headerShown: true,
            headerLeft: () => <></>,
          }}>
</Stack.Screen>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm using v6, it's works for me:

```js
 <Stack.Screen
    name="ApparelsHome"
    component={ApparelsHome}
    options={{
      headerLeft: () => <></>,
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

found it myself ;)
adding:

```js
  left: null,
```

disable the default back button.

```js
const MainStack = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Login",
      header: {
        visible: false,
      },
    },
  },
  FirstPage: {
    screen: FirstPage,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "FirstPage",
      header: {
        left: null,
      }
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

**react-navigation  versions >= 1.0.0-beta.9**

```js
navigationOptions:  {
   headerLeft: null
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For the latest version React Navigation 5 with Typescript:

```
<Stack.Screen
    name={Routes.Consultations}
    component={Consultations}
    options={{headerLeft: () => null}}
  />
```

Answer (score 4):

Since React Navigation v5.7, there's been a new official solution from the docs:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back

Use `beforeRemove` as a navigation listener to prevent back behavior from Android back button, header back button and custom back actions.

Comment: Yep - this is great for preventing transitions due to unsaved changes. If your goal is to prevent going back to a login or onboarding screen, however, then you can just do `navigation.replace` instead of `navigation.navigate`.

Answer (score 4):

**TO REMOVE BACK HEADER BUTTON**

```
 options={{ headerBackVisible:false,}}
```

*Full Tag*

```
<Stack.Screen name="Name" component={NameScreen} options={{ headerBackVisible:false,}} />
```

Answer (score 3):

The best option to handle this situation is to use SwitchNavigator provided by [React navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html#switchnavigatorconfig). The purpose of SwitchNavigator is to only ever show one screen at a time. By default, it does not handle back actions and it resets routes to their default state when you switch away. This is the exact behavior that is needed in the authentication flow.

This is a typical way to implement it.

1. Create 2 stack navigators: One for authentication (sign in, sign up, forgot password, etc) and another for the main APP
2. Create a screen in which you will check which route from switch navigator you want to show (I usually check this in splash screen by checking if a token is stored in Async storage)

**Here is a code implementation of above statements**

```js
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import HomeScreen from "./homeScreenPath" 
import OtherScreen from "./otherScreenPath"
import SignInScreen from "./SignInScreenPath" 
import SplashScreen from "./SplashScreenPath"

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen });

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });


export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      Splash: SplashScreen,
      App: AppStack,
      Auth: AuthStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Splash',
    }
  )
);
```

Now in SplashScreen you will check the token and navigate accordingly

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

class SplashScreen extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkIfLogin();
  }

  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  checkIfLogin = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this splash
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
  };

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

> Once you change routes in SwitchNavigator it removes the older route automatically and hence if you press the back button it will not take you to the auth/login screens anymore

Answer (score 2):

We can fix it by setting headerLeft to null

```js
static navigationOptions =({navigation}) => {
    return {
        title: 'Rechercher une ville',
        headerLeft: null,
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply doing

```
headerLeft: null
```

might be deprecated by the time you read this answer.
You should use following

```
   navigationOptions = {
        headerTitle : "Title",
        headerLeft : () => {},
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**ReactNavigation v 5.0 - Stack option:**

```
options={{
headerLeft: () => { 
 return <></>; 
}
}}
```

Comment: Please always describe what you are doing in your answer. It should be updated or removed. Read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before you provide more answers ^^

Answer (score 2):

```
import React,{useEffect,useState,useRef} from 'react';
import { BackHandler,View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => true)
    return () => backHandler.remove()
  }, [])

return(
<View>

</View>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [SwitchNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html) would be the way to accomplish this. `SwitchNavigator` resets the default routes and unmounts the authentication screen when the `navigate` action is invoked.

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

// Implementation of HomeScreen, OtherScreen, SignInScreen, AuthLoadingScreen
// goes here.

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen });
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
));
```

After the user goes to the SignInScreen and enters their credentials, you would then call

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react native expo CLI then you can simply use

options={{headerBackVisible:false}}

Comment: If you want to completely hide the header of stack.navigator on your page just add  options={{headerShown: false}}

Answer (score 1):

You can use

**options={{gestureEnabled: false}}**

this you can declare where you are declaring your screen.

```
      <AuthStack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashBoardContainer} options={{gestureEnabled: false}} />
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

In Latest Version (v2) works `headerLeft:null`. you can add in controller's `navigationOptions` as bellow

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerLeft: null,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For latest version of React Navigation, even if you use null in some cases it may still show "back" written!

Go for this in your **main app.js** under your screen name or just go to your **class file** and add: -

```
static navigationOptions = {
   headerTitle:'Disable back Options',
   headerTitleStyle: {color:'white'},
   headerStyle: {backgroundColor:'black'},
   headerTintColor: 'red',
   headerForceInset: {vertical: 'never'},
   headerLeft: " "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it is simple just add `headerLeft : null` , i am using react-native cli, so this is the example :

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerLeft : null
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**For react-navigation version 4.x**

```
navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: 'Configuration',
      headerBackTitle: null,
      headerLayoutPreset:'center',
      headerLeft: null
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
headerLeft: null
```

This won't work in the latest react native version

It should be:

```
navigationOptions = {
 headerLeft:()=>{},
}
```

For Typescript:

```
navigationOptions = {
 headerLeft:()=>{return null},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In react-navigation versions 5.x, you can do it like this:

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 1,
    routes: [
      { name: 'Home' },
      {
        name: 'Profile',
        params: { user: 'jane' },
      },
    ],
  })
);
```

You can read more [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset).

Answer (score 0):

Great Answers Provided Though, but i think this is quite simple

```
    useEffect(() => {
    props.navigation.addListener("beforeRemove", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }, [props.navigation]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `headerLeft:()=>false` to get rid of back button

```
<Stack.Screen name="ImageScreen" component={ShowImage} options={{title:"SMAART", headerLeft:()=>false}} />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have working on old project where used React Navigation Version 4
I tried but only things work is ..

```
passwordEntry: {
      screen: passwordEntry,
      navigationOptions: {
        gestureEnabled: false,
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

For react-native 0.73.x if you want to completely disable the back button on entire APP in just add into your MainActivity.kt:

```
...
 override fun onBackPressed() {
  //Do nothing or log? 
 }
...
```

Its overrides the backButton on entire Android activity.