# React Navigation Reset Can add parameters?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am still new to react navigation.
I wish to reset the route information after login successfully. However there is some parameters like login information I wish to pass to the main page.

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile',
                params:{user:this.state.username}})
      ]
  })
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

In the Profile page, I want to get access to the params, so I use this:

```
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state = { username: this.props.navigation.state.params.user, 
  }
```

but I received: **undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.state.params.user')** in the Console log.
May I know how should I get the parameters? Thank you

Answer (score 16):

Yes it can. React Navigation 5+ let's us easily use the navigation prop reset the routes history, then it allows us to pass a `params` property into the targeted route object.

```
navigation.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [{name: 'DriveInfosAdded', params: {data}}],
  });
```

Answer (score 10):

You can pass the params in reset action of react-native stack navigator like this:-

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [ 
                NavigationActions.navigate({ 
                    routeName: 'ScreenName',      // name of the screen you want to navigate
                    params: {
                        paramsKey: paramsValue   // this second parameter is for sending the params
                    } 
                })
            ],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

And get the parameter value in second screen from the navigation state params like this:-

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation, screenProps}) => {
    const params = navigation.state.params || {};   // You can get the params here as navigation.state.params.paramsKey

    console.log("CompareScreen product_id:", params.paramsKey);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This is working for me on React Navigation 5:

To reset the state of navigation, navigate to the screen 'OrderDetails' and pass the parameter 'orderCode' to this screen:

```
navigation.reset({index: 0, routes: [{ name: 'OrderDetails', params: { orderCode: 'whatever' } }] })
```

To retrieve the parameter orderCode in the new route 'OrderDetails':

```
function OrderDetails({theme, route, navigation}) {
const { orderCode } = route.params;
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing parameters by using `username` as key.
So when you are retrieving it your code should look like this

**Step 1: Pass params**

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Your-Screen_name',{ username: 'Lucy' })
```

**Step2: Get Params**

```
this.state = { 
    username: this.props.navigation.state.params.username, 
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have edit as you mentioned, but I still receive the same error message

Comment: Are you using redux structure?

Comment: Hi I think no, the guide I follow is from: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions . Redux is within the advance guide, and I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code. However, I still received this msg: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.state.params.username') in the Console log

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

1. Pass param:

`NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Location', params: { username: 'Luchi' }}),`

2. Get them:

`const params = this.props.navigation.state.params || {};
    if (!(params && params.username)) {
      alert('hi '+params.username)
    }`